# Files not loading properly from github host

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, hosting

I a trying to get my Calculator website to work via github.com (https://codingoni.github.io/bCalculator/)
When I open my index files from my local storage it works but when I try to go to the website it just shows

bCalculator I am assuming the css and javascript are not loading but I do not know why.

I have tried changing the directory

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./calc.css">
    <script src="./calc.js"></script>
```

The files have the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

**Check the route:**
You don't have an `index.html` file so GitHub is reading `README.md` instead when you request https://codingoni.github.io/bCalculator/ but it works fine when you access it at https://codingoni.github.io/bCalculator/calc.html.

Comment: Thank you! should i change my main file to index.html or should i change the url on github.com

Comment: @CodingOni I would change it to index.html - also pls mark the answer as the solution if it solved your issue.